# JPA + Hibernate: @ManyToMany relationship assignment for large collections

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

Let's say we have the following @ManyToMany relationship:

A User entity

```
 @Entity
    public class User {

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    ...
}
```

A Role entity

```
@Entity
public class Role  {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
    ...
}
```

The way to make @ManyToMany assignments is by doing the following:

```
role.getUsers().add(user);
user.getRoles().add(role);
```

However wouldn't that result in Hibernate/JPA going out and fetching all the entities in the collections on both sides of the relationship? What if the collections are really large - wouldn't that be a performance/memory issue? Is there a better way to handle assignments?

Comment: This is a common issue as Hibernate needs to load the complete collection to enforce uniqueness. One popular solution is to create a join table to handle the mapping between user/role via a UserRole entity. The UserRole entity can be as simple as a class with User and Role variables with methods to grant/revoke roles to user.

Comment: So that worked. I made the user-role assignment via a JoinTable. By adding a new row to the JoinTable, I was able to make the relationship assignment. The only issue is that the User.getRoles() and Role.getUsers() collections don't have the updated user_role assignment within the same transaction. If I flush the EM, detach the entities and look them up again, then the User and Role collections will reflect the assignment made via the JoinTable. It is still not ideal, however that is to be expected. I guess I can get get rid of User.getRoles() and Role.getUsers() to eliminate this issue.

Comment: If you would like to make your comment as an answer, I'd accept it. Thanks.